# Где найти реализации стандартных функций Си

Tags: c

Где можно найти реализации стандартных функций Си?
Искал в интернете - нашел только их обьявления, обьяснения и примеры использования...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Найти можно в исходниках, например в исходниках glibc.

Comment: Ссылку бы привел в ответе. а то слишком коротко http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/

Comment: @Mike тут не любят ответы-ссылки.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов тут ссылка уместна, потому что сказано, как она найдена. Не любят в основном ответы, состоящие только из ссылки.

Comment: Хоть и легко ищется в гугле (`glibc source code`), IMHO все же лучше не идти на поводу у ... и сразу дать какую-то  [удобоваримую ссылочку](https://github.com/lattera/glibc)

Comment: Ну увы, имеют негативный опыт :-)

Comment: Капля камень точит.